# Execute function in TabViewController from Child Element in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Tab View Controller, and inside of it is a Table View Controller.

When a table cell is tapped, I want to execute a function that ends with a segue that must be called from the Tab View.

However, while I can execute the function on the Table Cell tap, it won't call the parent function.

**Relevant code**

`SettingsTableViewController`

```
protocol settingsTableViewControllerDelegate {
    func settingsTableViewControllerDidPressButton(settingsTableViewController: SettingsTableViewController)
}

class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var delegate:settingsTableViewControllerDelegate?

    //...

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        let row = indexPath.row
        if row == 0 {
            let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Log Out", message: "Are you sure?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Log Out", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                print("Confirmed Log Out")
                self.delegate?.settingsTableViewControllerDidPressButton(self) } ))
            refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                print("Cancelled Log Out") } ))
            presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

`DashboardTabViewController`

```
class dashboardTabBarController: UITabBarController, settingsTableViewControllerDelegate {

    func settingsTableViewControllerDidPressButton(settingsTableViewController: SettingsTableViewController) {
        print("Executing log out function")
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.removeObjectForKey("email")
        defaults.removeObjectForKey("password")
        defaults.removeObjectForKey("userid")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("dashboardToHome", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

The "Confirmed Log Out" statement prints to console. but not the "Executing Log Out Function".

How can I call this function?

Comment: well, did you correctly hook up the `delegate` property? Looks like the delegate is `nil` and therefore the delegate method does not get invoked.

Comment: @luk2302 Apologies but I'm not experienced when it comes to Swift... What should I have in place of `nil`? I assume you mean where it says `sender: nil`?

Answer (score 0):

you should be using closures for this type of functionality. In your tab view controller you just need a reference to the table view controller by doing something like:

```
// in tab view controller viewDidLoad
let tableViewController = self.viewControllers[indexOfTableViewController] as! YourTableViewController
tableViewController.segueClosure = {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("segueId", sender: self)
}
```

and then at the end of the function "*that ends with a segue that must be called from the Tab View."*, you just call that closure:

```
// in YourTableViewController
segueClosure()
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work, but I get an error for `indexOfTableViewController` which states *Use of unresolved identifier indexOfTableViewController*

Comment: that's a variable i made up pal, it's supposed to mean figure out what the index of your table view controller is and make that index a variable